# Perl Regex to not match a repeated pattern

Tags: regex, perl, cisco

I am trying to determine whether a command I place on a cisco router, only has only neighbor entry inside the following output..

I have the following regex .. How do I get the search to fail if it reaches the end and doesn't find the second match?

```
if (! $document =~/(Device\sID)(.*?)(Device\sID)/s){        
    print("Theres no double entries\n");
} else { 
    print ("double!\n");
}
```

---

```
Device ID: NAME1
Entry address(es): 
  IP address: IP.IP.IP.IP
Plautform: cisco WS-C3850-48T,  Capabilities: Switch IGMP 
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/x,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernetx/x/x
Holdtime : 123 sec

Version :
Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software, Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 03.02.03.SE RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2013 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 23-Sep-13 18:24 by prod_rel_team

advertisement version: 2
VTP Management Domain: 'NAME1'
Native VLAN: 1
Duplex: full
Management address(es): 
  IP address: IP.IP.IP.IP
```

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Hey Peter, reread the first sentence of your question and perhaps rework it? *"...only has only neighbor entry inside the following output.."*  Can you give an example of somewhere this is a double, and somewhere there isn't a double?  If you're trying to see if there are duplicate Device ID's, then the easiest solution is to just pull them all and then look for duplicates.  But as things stand right now, it's unclear what your goal is with your given data and question.

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide a test condition and an output? Also I think it will be better to take off `!` from `if` and swap the body of `if` and `else`. I don't get what you mean by having the search fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem of operator precedence. `!` has an higher precedence than `=~`, so your expression:

```
 if ( ! $document =~ /(Device\sID)(.*?)(Device\sID)/s ) {
```

is the same that:

```
 if ( (! $document) =~ /(Device\sID)(.*?)(Device\sID)/s ) {
```

but you want:

```
 if ( ! ($document =~ /(Device\sID)(.*?)(Device\sID)/s) ) {
```

that is the same that:

```
 if ( $document !~ /(Device\sID)(.*?)(Device\sID)/s ) {
```

Comment: Thank you for this logic breakdown. Worked like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

`!~` is the operator for regex not matchd.

```
$document !~ /(Device\sID)(.*?)(Device\sID)/s
```

Comment: Yes much better than "match"  if else

Comment: This may be a useful reminder but it is irrelevant to the question and doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: @Borodin no, this is the answer. Using `!` inside the if condition is wrong with `=~`.  And OP wanted `How do I get the search to fail if it reaches the end and doesn't find the second match`, which goes with my answer.

Comment: I do appreciate the assistance on this. From one engineer to another!